# run bash script from linux partition, locate does not work

Tags: bash, scripts, locate

I am new to linux and I am currently trying to run a bash script from command line in a linux partition.

The partition is `/dev/sdb1` and the script runs other scripts that are placed in that partition.

I am using `loc="$(locate -b '\my_dir')"` but when I run the main bash script it gives me the following error:

```
main_script.sh: line 31: /my/dir/secondary_script.sh: No such file or directory
```

I did `sudo updatedb` but still no success.

It seems that the `locate` command works in the main partition but NOT in `/dev/sdb1`.

Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying that `locate` is failing to find the file, or that your script is unable to do something with (execute?) it? Which filesystems / mountpoints get indexed are controlled by `/etc/updatedb.conf` - but if the file *is* being located, that's not your issue

Comment: I am sorry. the issue here is that the locate command does not work in the partition where the scripts are. so the main script cannot find the secondary scripts....if I do e.g.  locate Desktop it works

Comment: So what is `\my_dir` and how does it relate to `/my/dir/secondary_script.sh` ? what is line 31 of `main_script.sh` ? obfuscating your filenames really doesn't help - in a question about locating files

Comment: \my_dir is the directory where the secondary scripts are. the full path is /my_dir/my/dir/secondary_script.sh

Comment: So is it `/my_dir/…` or `/\my_dir/…` now? The error message says `/my/dir/secondary_script.sh`! Those a all different directories! Please [edit] your question and completely provide every script involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that the locate command works in the main partition but NOT in  `/dev/sdb1`.

See `/etc/updatedb.conf`.

It will likely look like this:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs
 coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.gluster
fs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"
```

That is was locate does scan and what it skips in case you want to add something to the database. But this

```
main_script.sh: line 31: /my/dir/secondary_script.sh: No such file o directory
```

should be a problem in your script. `locate` does not show errors if it can not find a file.

Comment: thanks. the error shown is due to the main script trying to find the secondary scripts with locate. just checked and /etc/updatedb.conf looks like yours. my partition is in /media . but still don't know why it does not work

Comment: @2801001 if your `updatedb.conf` looks like the one above, then `/media` is in `PRUNEPATHS`

Comment: what's the meaning of it? please explain. should I remove /media from PRUNEPATHS?

Comment: That's for you to answer; locate does NOT search /media/ when it is in PRUNEPATHS.